# Ti-84+ CE giving n+0i instead of just n

Tags: ti-basic

So I made a program to solve any cubic equation. But it uses a lot of complex number trickery. And at the end. Even though the solutions are not complex, it gives a complex number. Is there any way to convert this n+0i into just n?
1,-6,11,-6 into my cubic program returns {1+0i,2+0i,3+0i} instead of {1,2,3} it’s not the end of the world, but it would be appreciated.